# Images displaying with zero height & width after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, svg

I have a site in development which uses ajax page loading. This all works as expected except when it comes to images.

If you visit the link below, you will see a page title "Brands" which has an svg icon followed by an img.

Now if you click "Brands" in the sidebar the page will fade out, fetch the same page via the .load method and then fade in the content. However you will notice in Chrome that the svg is seemingly missing. If you check in safari the svg is visible but the img is missing. If you check it in Firefox then you get the alt attribute displayed.

After inspecting the page you will notice that they have a height of 0px and a width of 0px.

Why is happening and how can I resolve it?

http://kga.creativelittledevs.co.uk/consultant/brands/

I did try an create a reduced test case but it wasnt very easy to replicate.

Here's my full ajax code:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "decodeHTML", {

    value: function () {

        return $('<div>', {html: '' + this}).html();

    }

});

var init = function() {

        $('select').selectric({

            arrowButtonMarkup:'<svg class="selectric__button"><use xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#icon-right-chevron"></use></svg>'

        }, 'refresh');

    },
    ajaxLoad = function(html) {

        document.title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1].trim().decodeHTML();

        init();

    },
    loadPage = function(href, get, put) {

        $(put).fadeOut(200, function(){

            $(put).load(href + ' ' + get, function(){

                ajaxLoad;

                $(put).fadeIn(200);

            });

        });

    };

init();

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {

    var state = e.originalEvent.state;

    if (state !== null) {

        loadPage(location.href, state.get, state.put);

    } else {

        history.pushState({get: '.app-main > *', put: '.app-main'}, '', location.href);

    }

});

kga.doc.on('click', '.js-ajax', function() {

    var $this   = $(this),
        href    = $this.attr('href'),
        get     = $this.data('ajax-get') ? $this.data('ajax-get') + ' > *' : '.app-main > *',
        put     = $this.data('ajax-put') ? $this.data('ajax-put') : '.app-main';

    if (href.indexOf(document.domain) > -1 || href.indexOf(':') === -1) {

        history.pushState({get: get, put: put}, '', href);

        loadPage(href, get, put);

        return false;
    }

});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: We can't help you with this as the code provided does cannot show us what's wrong - the AJAX request will simply load the returned code into the div provided, and any image will be simply be set by the code returned by you. The code provided does not do anything with images at all, so it cannot influence it. Also, on Safari 8 I am seeing both fine and nothing is missing. Chrome has the issue, though.

Comment: This is whats strange, that code does not have any influence in images as you say it's just there for reference. Im using safari 9. Did you get a chance to look at firefox. Also what can I provide to help illustrate the issue. Surely the browser should just see the images and display them correctly?

Comment: I am unsure since I only have the issue with your SVG, and I am unsure how exactly the `use` elements does its thing and what could go wrong with that.